# Can't reload next ViewController in PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I can't update next page in my PageViewController.

1. I add the required number of controllers, but the `pageController.setViewControllers([controllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: false)` method leaves us with one.
2. I have information for each next controller taken from the viewModel and updated when the currentIndex counter changes
3. In the viewControllerBefore and viewControllerAfter methods, I initialize my view controller and increase or decrease currentIndex when scrolling forward or backward
4. After that, the didSet in the view controller works for me and the update takes place.
5. But, in the end, instead of 8 controllers, I only see 2.

PageViewController

```
class PageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

let viewModel: GeneralViewModel

let locationViewModel: LocationViewModel

let realm = try! Realm()

var pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()

var pageController: UIPageViewController!

var controllers = [UIViewController]()

var pendingIndex = 0

init(viewModel: GeneralViewModel, locationViewModel: LocationViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    self.locationViewModel = locationViewModel
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll,
                                                  navigationOrientation: .horizontal,
                                                  options: nil)
    pageController.delegate = self
    pageController.dataSource = self
    
    
    
    addChild(pageController)
    view.addSubview(pageController.view)
    
    let views = ["pageController": pageController.view] as [String: AnyObject]
            view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[pageController]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
            view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[pageController]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    
    for _ in realm.objects(Cities.self) {

        let mainScreenViewController = MainScrenenViewController(viewModel: self.viewModel, locationViewModel: self.locationViewModel)
        
        self.controllers.append(mainScreenViewController)
    }
    
    pageController.setViewControllers([controllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: false)
    
    setupPageControl()

}

func setupPageControl() {
    
    let realmCities = realm.objects(Cities.self)
    
    pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 100,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
    pageControl.numberOfPages = realmCities.count
    pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    view.addSubview(pageControl)
   
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) {
            if index > 0 {
                let mainScreenViewController = MainScrenenViewController(viewModel: self.viewModel, locationViewModel: self.locationViewModel)
                
                mainScreenViewController.currentIndex -= 1
                
                controllers.append(mainScreenViewController)
                
                return controllers[index - 1]
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    return nil
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) {
            if index < controllers.count - 1 {
             
            let mainScreenViewController = MainScrenenViewController(viewModel: self.viewModel, locationViewModel: self.locationViewModel)
                
            mainScreenViewController.currentIndex += 1
                
            controllers.append(mainScreenViewController)
                
            return controllers[index + 1]
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
}
```

MainScreenViewController

```
class MainScrenenViewController: UIViewController, ChangeWeatherDelegate {

let viewModel: GeneralViewModel

let locationViewModel: LocationViewModel

var currentIndex = 0 {
    didSet {
        mainCollectionView.reloadData()
        todayCollectionView.reloadData()
        weekCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

//MARK: -Realm
let realm = try! Realm()
```

Comment: You have already created your view controllers in viewDidLoad then why you are again recreating them in viewControllerBefore & viewControllerAfter, in viewControllerBefore & viewControllerAfter you just need to access already created view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad()` in `PageViewController`, you are doing this:

```
for _ in realm.objects(Cities.self) {

    let mainScreenViewController = MainScrenenViewController(viewModel: self.viewModel, locationViewModel: self.locationViewModel)
    
    self.controllers.append(mainScreenViewController)
}
```

so, you've created an array of 8 `MainScreenViewController` objects.

However, you haven't set `.currentIndex` on them, so they currently are all `currentIndex = 0`.

Then, in `viewControllerBefore` and `viewControllerAfter`, instead of getting the *already created* view controller from your `controllers` array, you are ***creating another** instance of `MainScreenViewController` and setting its `.currentIndex` to either `-= 1` or `+= 1` ... but then you're ***appending*** it to `controllers`.

Your code then returns a controller at `index - 1` or `index + 1` from the controllers array.

It may help if you start a bit simpler... get your `UIPageViewController` working... and *then* add in the code for your view and location models.

Here's a quick example - based on your code - that adds a centered label. showing the "index" of each page:

```
class MainScrenenViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var currentIndex: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "\(currentIndex)"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

class PageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    
    var pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
    
    var pageController: UIPageViewController!
    
    var controllers = [UIViewController]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll,
                                              navigationOrientation: .horizontal,
                                              options: nil)
        pageController.delegate = self
        pageController.dataSource = self
        
        addChild(pageController)
        view.addSubview(pageController.view)
        pageController.didMove(toParent: self)

        let views = ["pageController": pageController.view] as [String: AnyObject]
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[pageController]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[pageController]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        
        for i in 0..<8 {
            
            let mainScreenViewController = MainScrenenViewController()
            mainScreenViewController.currentIndex = i
            self.controllers.append(mainScreenViewController)
        }
        
        pageController.setViewControllers([controllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: false)
        
        setupPageControl()
    }
    
    func setupPageControl() {
        
        pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 100,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
        pageControl.numberOfPages = self.controllers.count
        pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        view.addSubview(pageControl)
        
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        
        if let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) {
            if index > 0 {

                return controllers[index - 1]

            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) {
            if index < controllers.count - 1 {
                
                return controllers[index + 1]

            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already created your view controllers in viewDidLoad then why you are again recreating them in viewControllerBefore & viewControllerAfter ?, in viewControllerBefore & viewControllerAfter you just need to access already created view controllers, I have updated you code.

```
class PageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource
    {
        var pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
        var pageController: UIPageViewController!
        var controllers = [UIViewController]()
        var pendingIndex = 0
       
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll,
                                                          navigationOrientation: .horizontal,
                                                          options: nil)
            pageController.delegate = self
            pageController.dataSource = self
            addChild(pageController)
            view.addSubview(pageController.view)
            
            let views = ["pageController": pageController.view] as [String: AnyObject]
                    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[pageController]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
                    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[pageController]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
            
            for index in 0 ..< 10
            {
                let mainScreenViewController = MainScrenenViewController()
                mainScreenViewController.currentIndex = index
                mainScreenViewController.view.backgroundColor = index % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.red : UIColor.blue
                self.controllers.append(mainScreenViewController)
            }
            
            pageController.setViewControllers([controllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: false)
            
            setupPageControl()
    
        }
    
        func setupPageControl() {
                    
            pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 100,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
            pageControl.numberOfPages = 10
            pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
            pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
            pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
            pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            view.addSubview(pageControl)
           
        }
    
        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
        {
            guard var index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else
            {
                return nil
            }
            
            if (index == 0)
            {
                return nil
            }
            
            index -= 1
            return controllers[index]
        }
    
        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
        {
            guard var index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else
            {
                return nil
            }
            
            index += 1
            
            if (index >= controllers.count)
            {
                return nil
            }
            
            return controllers[index]
        }
        
        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
        {
            if completed == true
            {
                if let pageIndex = (pageViewController.viewControllers?.first as? MainScrenenViewController)?.currentIndex
                {
                    pageControl.currentPage = pageIndex
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    
    class MainScrenenViewController: UIViewController/*, ChangeWeatherDelegate*/
    {
        var currentIndex = 0
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            loadData()
        }
        
        func loadData()
        {
            /*mainCollectionView.reloadData()
            todayCollectionView.reloadData()
            weekCollectionView.reloadData()*/
        }
    }
```